# How do you setup random email server?

Tags: email, email-server

Basically, my end goal is to have an email server which can randomly generate email addresses. People can then send attachments to these addresses, and if sent the correct email, it will attach the file to their account on my application.

What I'm looking for is very similar to Posterous' email system, which generates one email address for you to email your blog posts to.

It's also similar to Facebook's comment-email system, where it sends you an email every time you get a notifications (you got tagged, someone commented on something you posted, etc), and all replies sent to that email are recorded as comments to the specific notification.

How is this done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An implementation similar to BATV (Bounce Address Tag Verification) should be able to handle this.  The tag would be tied to a post.  The MDA would need to be aware of the tags and respond appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I believe qmail has a lot of different "hooks" for running external programs on incoming email.

Answer (score -1):

Set up the email server to send all mail to an inbound script or a single account which is processed by a script. Google the email program you're using and catchall or wildcard forward to get specific instructions.